# while loop conditions java

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

```
String userGuessParameters = "a,b";

while (!Character.isDigit(userGuessParameters.charAt(0)) || 
       !Character.isDigit(userGuessParameters.charAt(2)) ||
       userGuessParameters.length() != 3 || 
       (int)(userGuessParameters.charAt(0)) >= parameters[0] || 
       (int)(userGuessParameters.charAt(2)) >= parameters[1]) {

    System.out.print("Mida kaevame (rida, veerg): ");
    userGuessParameters = userInput.nextLine();
    userGuessParameters = userGuessParameters.replaceAll(" ", "");
}
```

I'm trying to check if all the required conditions are fulfilled in the while loop. `parameters` is what user entered in array form. Let's assume `parameters = [4, 4]` (Parameters is used to create a 4x4 map).

I need `userGuessParameters` to be:

1. Numbers
2. Length equal to 3 (the input looks like this: 2,2 when the spaces are removed)
3. Smaller than the biggest coordinate (which is 3,3)

But for some reason, the loop never exits. I'm almost certain it is because of the last two conditions in the while loop, but I can't find the mistake.

Answer (score 3):

You are using the logical `OR` operator when you should be using `AND` (you want *all* the conditions to be met, not just *at least one of them*).

Use the [java notation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html) for `AND` which is `&&`:

```
(!Character.isDigit(userGuessParameters.charAt(0)) &&
!Character.isDigit(userGuessParameters.charAt(2)) &&
userGuessParameters.length() != 3 &&
(int)(userGuessParameters.charAt(0)) >= parameters[0] &&
(int)(userGuessParameters.charAt(2)) >= parameters[1])
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `&&` instead of `||` like this:

```
   while (!Character.isDigit(userGuessParameters.charAt(0)) && !Character.isDigit(userGuessParameters.charAt(2))
       && userGuessParameters.length() != 3 && (int)(userGuessParameters.charAt(0)) >= parameters[0]
       && (int)(userGuessParameters.charAt(2)) >= parameters[1]) {
```